# Creating a custom reusable user control in WPF, figuring out how to combine the progress bar and the slider bar?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

In WPF, I need to create a custom user control. It looks something like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to create a slider control with a tick, that has the values filled in from an external data source.

In short, the program runs a test, and it displays the results in the user control (shown in the image above). The user cannot modify the user control. It is read only.

The colors also change based on the number as well. That's self exploratory based on the picture.

I tried creating a slidercontrol and tried to fill in what I need. I also tried to create a progressbar, and trying to draw the tick. I know I will have to use databinding for the numbers to be displayed on the user control.

Unfortunately, I am at the part where "I don't know where I don't know." I am not that good at creating custom WPF controls (yet).

Can somebody help me create this?

Comment: You don't need a custom control. You need a standard slider control with a custom ControlTemplate. I'd start with the standard template: Create a Slider in XAML, go to Design mode in the designer ("Design" tab at lower left), right click on the slider control in the design view, and select "Edit Template" | "Edit a Copy..." from the context menu. You're in for a bit of a learning curve, but if you run into specific snags along the way, you can ask further questions here. When you do, be sure to be [very clear and complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Here is a question, what property disables the user interaction of scrolling the tick?

Comment: What user interaction of scrolling the tick? You mean you don't want to let the user interact with it at all? Set IsEnabled="False" for that. The default template may look grayed out then, but yours doesn't have to.

Comment: What determines the background brush change? Different thresholds for each instance? I didn't originally notice that it can't be the same set of thresholds for all of them (there's a yellow at 80% and a green at 70%). For that, I think you do actually want a subclass of Slider with additional dependency properties for three brushes and two thresholds. You could do it with attached properties too, but a subclass is cleaner.

Comment: I never customized WPF objects at this level before with MS Blend. I appreciate the help so far. The IsEnabled=False, I ended up doing that and changing the color before I saw this message. I have learned a lot from this experience so far! When you mentioned "Subclass of Slider with additional dependency properties" now I feel a little lost. I am not sure what that exactly means. As in, I can't think "how would I do this in XAML?"

Comment: You don't write a subclass in XAML, you'd do that in C#. Any Blend-related questions are hopeless with me, I've never used it.

Comment: Also, yes. The different levels (such as 40% is red, 65% is yellow, and 75% is green) does determine the background brush color of the slider object.

How do I fill out the background up to the thumb object? I can keep on looking into this, if you can't answer that at this time.

Comment: I would have two public dependency properties in my class named LowThreshold and HighThreshold. Make them integers, a percentage. Then write a MultiValueConverter which you bind to LowThreshold, HighThreshold, and Value, and it'll return a brush based on where Value is relative to those two thresholds.

Comment: Then in the (win10) template I've got in front of me, there's a Border in `<ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderHorizontal"` named `x:Name="TrackBackground"`. By default here it's a gray bar from left to right. In there, I'd put a left-aligned Rectangle in there with its Fill determined with the above multivalueconverter. I'd figure out how to get the actual thumb position (no clue how, but it's got to be doable) and bind that to the Rectangle's width. Told you there was a learning curve. For all I know there may be an easier way in Blend to do some of this stuff.

Comment: Somebody got the slider position [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19722644/424129): The "decrease button" is, I think, the clickable are to the left of the slider, which naturally will be what we're looking for

Comment: Correction: That Rectangle should be a sibling of TrackBackground.

Comment: Thank you. I am still looking into this.

Comment: I ended up kicking it around a good bit, so let me know if you run into any trouble.

Comment: How would you change the color based on the percentage or its position? I am struggling on this point. I was thinking of using a trigger? Also, I looked at what you sent to me. That was very helpful!

Comment: A trigger won't work. A trigger fires on "a equals b", but we need "a <= b". You'd have to write a converter anyway, so you may as well write a converter that just returns a brush. See answer.

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely helpful.

Comment: Doing it this way and working out the problem is extremely helpful. I am being pushed beyond my capabilities as a developer. I am not used to this level of XAML. I appreciate you helping me out.

Comment: No prob, it's fun.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need. What Ed said is very helpful.

One thing that I will add is that I used the Prism MVVM Framework. You can read more about Prism here: https://prismlibrary.github.io/

**ResultBarControl.xaml:**

```
    <UserControl x:Class="ResultBarControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ManualControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PassBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1" >
                <GradientStop Color="#287d02" Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="#64ce0b" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="#287d02" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="FailBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1" >
                <GradientStop Color="#db0000" Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="#ff5050" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="#db0000" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="InactiveBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1" >
                <GradientStop Color="#e5e5e5" Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="#E3E3E3" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="#cfcfcf" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="RunningBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1" >
                <GradientStop Color="#ffa600" Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="#ffdf2b" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="#ffa600" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>

            <Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle" TargetType="Thumb">
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="false"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="15"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                            <Canvas>
                                <Polygon Points="0,0 5,10, 10,0" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" />
                            </Canvas>

                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="Slider">
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                            <Grid>

                                <Border Name="PART_Border" 
                            BorderThickness="0" 
                            Padding="2"
                            CornerRadius="5" 
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
                            Height="12"

                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                            VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Border.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TestStatus}" Value="Pass">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PassBrush}"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TestStatus}" Value="Inactive">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource InactiveBrush}"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TestStatus}" Value="Fail">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource FailBrush}"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TestStatus}" Value="Running">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource RunningBrush}"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Border.Style>
                                </Border>
                                <Track Name="PART_Track" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Track.Thumb>
                                        <Thumb Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" />
                                    </Track.Thumb>
                                </Track>
                            </Grid>

                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                                    <Setter TargetName="PART_Border" Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="PART_Border" Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Height="65" Margin="5,2,5,2" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Height="25" FontFamily="{DynamicResource TextFont}"  Foreground="#727272" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Height="25" FontFamily="{DynamicResource TextFont}"  Foreground="#727272" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Run Text="{Binding Value}" FontSize="15" BaselineAlignment="Bottom"  />
            <Run Text="{Binding Unit}" FontSize="13"   BaselineAlignment="Bottom" />
        </TextBlock>
        <Slider Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="20" Grid.Row="1" 
                Value="{Binding Value}" 
                Maximum="{Binding Max}" 
                Minimum="{Binding Min}" 
                AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft" 
                AutoToolTipPrecision="1"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Height="20"  FontFamily="{DynamicResource TextFont}"  Foreground="#727272" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Min}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="20"  FontFamily="{DynamicResource TextFont}"  Foreground="#727272" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Max}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ResultBarViewModel.cs:**

```
using Prism.Events;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ManualControls
{
    public class ResultBarViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private string testStatus { get; set; }
        private double? min { get; set; }
        private double? max { get; set; }
        private double? resultvalue { get; set; }
        private string title { get; set; }
        private string unit { get; set; }
        private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

        public ResultBarViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ReadDataEvent>().Subscribe(RefreshResultData);
        }

        private void RefreshResultData(ReadDataPayload payload)
        {

        }

        public string TestStatus
        {
            get
            {
                return testStatus;
            }
            set
            {
                testStatus = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public double? Min
        {
            get { return min; }
            set { min = value; }
        }
        public double? Max
        {
            get { return max; }
            set { max = value; }
        }
        public double? Value
        {
            get
            {
                return resultvalue;
            }
            set
            {
                resultvalue = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return title;
            }
            set
            {
                title = value;
            }
        }
        public string Unit
        {
            get
            {
                return unit;
            }
            set
            {
                unit = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```